# prevent creation of namelink for installed shared libraries when using CPack

Tags: c++, cmake, cpack

I'm building two packages in a distribution:

1. runtime shared library package
2. dev libary package

The problem is to include a correct symlink into any of them. Currently I use:

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES 
                        SOVERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}"
                        VERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION}")
```

and when specifying the following `CPack` configuration:

```
install (TARGETS mylib
          LIBRARY
          DESTINATION /usr/lib
          COMPONENT runtime)

install (TARGETS mylib
          LIBRARY
          DESTINATION /usr/lib
          COMPONENT dev)

install (DIRECTORY include/
          DESTINATION /usr/include/mylib 
          COMPONENT dev)
```

the runtime shared library package then contains the following symlink chain:

```
/usr/lib/libmylib.so -> libmylib.so.0
/usr/lib/libmylib.so.0 -> libmylib.so.0.0.1
/usr/lib/libmylib.so.0.0.1
```

The problem is `/usr/lib/libmylib.so -> libmylib.so.0` is redundant in the runtime shared library package since it is only necessary when building a binary that uses this `libmylib`.

***Question:*** Is there a way to excelude that `/usr/lib/libmylib.so -> libmylib.so.0` symlink from runtime shared library package?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the `NAMELINK_SKIP` parameter of the [`install(TARGETS)` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-targets).

> `NAMELINK_SKIP`
>
> Similar to `NAMELINK_ONLY`, but it has the opposite effect: it causes the installation of library files other than the namelink when a library target is installed. When neither `NAMELINK_ONLY` or `NAMELINK_SKIP` are given, both portions are installed. On platforms where versioned shared libraries do not have symlinks or when a library is not versioned, `NAMELINK_SKIP` installs the library. It is an error to use this parameter outside of a `LIBRARY` block.
>
> If `NAMELINK_SKIP` is specified, `NAMELINK_COMPONENT` has no effect. It is not recommended to use `NAMELINK_SKIP` in conjunction with `NAMELINK_COMPONENT`.