# How can I prevent CMake from creating a symlink for shared libraries on build (not on install)?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, bulletphysics

I am building a project on linux with Bullet3 using CMake, and when building the entire solution it builds the output libraries of Bullet with the SOVERSION appended and creates a symlink without the version.

I do not like this behavior for my specific scenario, and I don't want to edit the bullet submodule's CMakeLists file.

Here's my CMake where I include bullet libs:

```
    set(USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    
    set(BUILD_BULLET3 OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(BUILD_EGL OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(BUILD_ENET OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(BUILD_PYBULLET OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(BUILD_OPENGL3_DEMOS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(BUILD_BULLET2_DEMOS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(BUILD_EXTRAS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(BUILD_UNIT_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    
    set(INSTALL_LIBS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(USE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(USE_GRAPHICAL_BENCHMARK OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(USE_SOFT_BODY_MULTI_BODY_DYNAMICS_WORLD OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(BUILD_CPU_DEMOS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(USE_GLUT OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    SET(INTERNAL_CREATE_MSVC_RELATIVE_PATH_PROJECTFILES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    SET(INTERNAL_ADD_POSTFIX_EXECUTABLE_NAMES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

    add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/bullet3")
```

I would like the resulting bullet libs to be only one file per lib in the build directory, not two, doesn't matter if it has the version appended or not... I just don't want a symlink there.

I know I could simply run a script after to delete these but that would break my workflow big time at the moment.

Surely there must be a way to tell CMake not to do that?

I've read about `NAMELINK_SKIP` but if I understand correctly that is for the `INSTALL` command, but I am not even using the install command and I don't intend to in my project, I am currently getting the symlinks just with the initial build.

Comment: why don't you want the symlink there? Is it for personal/aesthetic reasons? Or is there an "engineering" reason?

Comment: related for those who care about install and not build: [prevent creation of namelink for installed shared libraries when using CPack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56281702/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

The target you are speaking of probably has either or both of the `VERSION` and `SOVERSION` properties set. The CMake docs for the [`VERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VERSION.html) and [`SOVERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SOVERSION.html) target properties state (emphasis added):

> For shared libraries [`VERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VERSION.html) and [`SOVERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SOVERSION.html) can be used to specify the build version and API version respectively. **When building** or installing **appropriate symlinks are created if the platform supports symlinks and the linker supports so-names**. If only one of both is specified the missing is assumed to have the same version number.

What you can do is unset them with the following:

```
set_property(TARGET target_name_here PROPERTY VERSION)
set_property(TARGET target_name_here PROPERTY SOVERSION)
```

The above code would go *after* the `add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/bullet3")`.

This also means no symlinks for the installation. If you still wanted to have symlinks for the installation, I don't know how you'd do that.